# Is $x^2$ function differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

My book says that $x^2$ function is differentiable at $x=0$.  How is this possible, given that the right limit is greater than zero and the left limit is less than zero?

Comment: No problem at all.  As the value of the two limits are evaluated at $x=0$ they are the same:  $0$.  The right limit is greater than *or equal to* $0$; the left limit is less than *or equal to* $0$.

Comment: both limits are $0$

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: What does “the right limit is greater than zero” mean? Can you be more precise please?

Comment: I mean the slope of the tangent to the curve from the right

Comment: Do you mean “the right side derivative at x=0”, or “the limit of the *derivative function* as x tends to 0”? Because those two things are not necessarily the same.

Comment: "2x" as no restriction over IR so its ok.

Comment: Why do you think that the right limit is not $0$ ? And also the left ? $2x$ tends to $0$ , no matter how $x$ approaches $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Both limits are $0.$ The function $x^2$ is always positive regardless of the sign of $x.$ Thus, it *has to be* the case that the right limit must be equal to the left limit as well.

Comment: Then what is the difference between this function and absolute function

Comment: Define $f(x)$ to be the absolute function. Then $\lim_{h \to 0^{-} } \frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{h} = -1 \neq 1 = \lim_{h \to 0^{+} } \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Comment: However, if you do the same thing with $g(x) = x^2$ by taking left and right limits, you see that both the left and the right limit is 0, so $g’(0) = 0$. Sorry, I wrote this out properly before but I’m on my phone and the math SE app keeps crashing when I try to copy text or edit posts, so that’s the best I got

Comment: I can find it algebraically but both functions look similar graphically

Comment: @emanahmed For $|x|,$ the limit at $0$ is also $0.$ But to find the derivative at $0,$ you are not considering this limit, but the limit of the quantity $$f{(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta},$$ as $\delta\to 0.$ If you do this for $x^2,$ you get $0.$ If you do it for $|x|,$ you get both $-1$ and $+1.$ Thus there is no definite value for the derivative of $|x|$ at the origin. This is why we say it is not differentiable there.

Comment: @emanahmed No, they're not similar graphically. The squaring function gives a smooth curve, a parabola. The absolute value gives a symmetric V-shaped graph however.

Comment: I got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

See them graphically....

[image: abs]
The absolute value has a corner at the origin, it changes direction suddently

[image: x2]
The parabola $x^2$ changes direction gradually